# Solving 3x3 Sudoku with SPARQL and OWL

Tags: sparql, owl, wikidata-query-service

I'm trying to solve simple 3x3 Sudoku game inside query.wikidata.org using SPARQL and OWL.

[image: 3x3 Sudoku game]

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
SELECT ?a12 ?a13 ?a21 ?a23 ?a31 ?a32 WHERE{

:Zahl a owl:Class;
        owl:oneOf (:1 :2 :3) .

 
?a12 a :Zahl.
?a13 a :Zahl.
?a21 a :Zahl.
?a23 a :Zahl.
?a31 a :Zahl.
?a32 a :Zahl.
       
?a11 owl:sameAs :1.
?a22 owl:sameAs :2.
?a33 owl:sameAs :3.

?a12 owl:differentFrom ?a11 ?a13 ?a22 ?a32.
?a13 owl:differentFrom ?a11 ?a12 ?a23 ?a33.
?a21 owl:differentFrom ?a22 ?a23 ?a11 ?a31.
?a23 owl:differentFrom ?a22 ?a21 ?a13 ?a33.
?a31 owl:differentFrom ?a11 ?a21 ?a32 ?a33.
?a32 owl:differentFrom ?a12 ?a22 ?a31 ?a33.
}
```

But i get this error:

```
Query is malformed: Encountered " <PNAME_LN> "owl:oneOf "" at line 5, column 19.
```

Could somebody please point out my mistake?

Comment: You want to run it with which SPARQL API?

Comment: And what about the `owl:differentFrom` lines? There are commas missing between each `à_i`, i.e. `?a12 owl:differentFrom ?a11, ?a13, ?a22, ?a32.` I hope you understand why if you know that Turtle notation is the syntax.

Comment: @AKSW I want to run it in blazegraph. www.blazegraph.com

Comment: @AKSW wow. I'm so embarrassed right now.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: By the way, the first two triple patterns `:Zahl a owl:Class;
        owl:oneOf (:1 :2 :3) .` don't make any sense, they do not contribute to the result of the query. None of them contains variables, thus, no join with others

Comment: @AKSW I fixed ```??a12 owl:differentFrom ?a11,?a13,?a22,?a32.``` but still get  this error ```Query is malformed: QName ':Zahl' uses an undefined prefix``` in query.wikidata.org and this error in blazegraph ```ERROR: SPARQL-QUERY: queryStr=prefix owl:```

Comment: Your prefix declaration `:` is missing. Just as a comment, it doesn't make sense to run your query on the Wikidata endpoint. Your data isn't loaded there, so what should mathc there?

Comment: @AKSW I want to say that Zahl is a class that could only accept 1 2 3 and my variables are belong to this class.

Comment: That's nothing that you can define in a SPARQL query, but has to be contained in the data.

Comment: To keep it short: What you're doing here is the wrong approach. I know this exercise, e.g. from [here](http://semantic-web-grundlagen.de/w/images/f/f3/Uebung3_queries.pdf) . But those conditions have to be expressed using the SPARQL language, not as OWL. For example, "Each number can only appear once in a row" has to be translated to something like `?a11 != ?a12 && ?a11 != a13 && ?a12 != ?a13` and so on and so furth.

Comment: [Here](https://blogs.sap.com/2009/04/15/semantic-web-technologies-part-1-sparql/) is one possble way described how to solve Sudoku with SPARQL.

Comment: @AKSW Thank you very much. I Solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello my fellow friend from Karlsruhe,

your basic mistake is that you try to define objects in your query - 
:Zahl a owl:Class;
        owl:oneOf (:1 :2 :3) .

The query is not the place for that. This can only be done in the rdf document - which should not be changed in the exercise.
Another mistake is a wrong understanding of objects and literals:
...owl:oneOf (:1 :2 :3) .
...
?a11 owl:sameAs :1.
?a22 owl:sameAs :2.
?a33 owl:sameAs :3.

owl:sameAs does not wirk on literals, so these are objects named 1, 2, and 3. You could work with objects named 1,2,3, but it is a lot easier to work with numbers (literals) and use filters (FILTER (?a11 = 1)).

Based on our source rdf, i think this is the way things should be done, as these are defined literals: 
ex:field ex:allowed "1"^^xsd:int,
"2"^^xsd:int,
"3"^^xsd:int.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As HarrySack_overflow already mentioned, the definition for :Zahl (in the exercise it's :field) is already in the graph (after all you are querying, not defining). :field can be defined and uploaded to the graph like this:

```
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

ex:field ex:allowed "1"^^xsd:int,
"2"^^xsd:int,
"3"^^xsd:int.
```

We can find a solution by querying all allowed values for the other fields, by `:field :allowed <<fieldVariableName>> .`

Finally, we check all solutions vor validity. In a 3x3 Sudoku where one value is already given for each row/column, this can be achieved by checking the sum for each row/column. The solution may look like this (the predefined fields are assigned to variables for better readability):

```
PREFIX : <http://example.org/> 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?a1 ?a2 ?a3 ?b1 ?b2 ?b3 ?c1 ?c2 ?c3
WHERE {
  BIND("1"^^xsd:integer AS ?a1)
  BIND("2"^^xsd:integer AS ?b2)
  BIND("3"^^xsd:integer AS ?c3)

  :field :allowed ?a2, ?a3, ?b1, ?b3, ?c1, ?c2 .

  #CHECK ROWS
  FILTER(?a1 + ?a2 + ?a3 = 6)
  FILTER(?b1 + ?b2 + ?b3 = 6)
  FILTER(?c1 + ?c2 + ?c3 = 6)

  #CHECK COLUMNS
  FILTER(?a1 + ?b1 + ?c1 = 6)
  FILTER(?a2 + ?b2 + ?c2 = 6)
  FILTER(?a3 + ?b3 + ?c3 = 6)
}
```